# Client-side random numbers without using javascript (targeting lynx & cli)

Tags: html, random

I've got an odd question here...

I want to generate some random values client side... except I'm focusing on web browsers like Lynx and cli interactions for this, which don't have access to javascript.

I've tried using html code

```
<random></random>
```

But that apparently doesn't exist.

I thought about generating a random image, but I'd have to do that server-side and send it. It can be anything, as long as it's random.

I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible.

JavaScript is the most common tool for generating random numbers. Nothing that doesn't support it supports any of the less popular options (such as VBScript).

If you want Lynx to display something random, it has to be generated server-side.